# HTTP 500 error when submitting form from certain computer

Tags: apache-2.2, 500-error

We are developing a website on a server, but we have a problem. One of our developers started getting a Internal Server Error (500) when he submits a form. It only happens with forms that use `post` as a method. The apache error is:

`Handler for x-httpd-php5 returned invalid result code 70007, referer: http://example.com/page`

The problem only occurs on his laptop (and only his laptop so far), regardless of the browser he uses and regardless of the WiFi network he is connected to (different ISP each time). He tried a system restore of his laptop without any luck. He built a VM on his laptop with Windows 8 and is able to post forms within the VM. He is able to submit post forms on other websites hosted on the same server. He is not using a proxy or a firewall on his laptop that can cause the error. We cleared the server and added a single test.php with just a form and a submit button, it gives the same error.

The server uses the following:

- CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
- Apache 2.2.21
- DirectAdmin 1.41.1
- Php 5.3.22

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error? The fact that only his laptop has the problem suggests that it is a client-side problem. We are however struggeling to find anything on the laptop that could be causing this error.

-edit-
Rebooting the laptop in safe-mode allows the developer to submit forms again. It seems to be a client-side problem. More ideas as to what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Does the Developers machine perhaps run a local Proxy or debugging aid like Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/)?

Comment: @Rainer.R, there is no local proxy being used.

Comment: Perhaps installing Wireshark on the Laptop and analyzing the traffic when doing the post will give some hint...

Comment: @Rainer.R We tried already, no luck either :(

Comment: Oy... perhaps you need to get a different Developer then ;)
Just a shot in the dark - does the relevant form perhaps handle file uploads (enctype="multipart/form-data") which may cause the error?

Comment: Haha, that's like getting a new racecar driver because yours can't change a spare. Just a form that submits (the submit button is the only value added to the POST array) gives this error. As I stated in my update, windows in safe-mode solves the problem. It's just not verry nice to develop in safe-mode, haha.

Comment: Ha ha ha. Sorry, out of idea's, hope you find a better solution than safe-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting the computer in safe-mode solved the problem. We now knew that it was client-side problem. By starting up applications one-by-one we found out the problem was AVG-Antivirus. We suspect it was a browser plug-in of some sort. AVG is not being used as a firewall by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this typically is caused by a firewall or proxy slowing down the traffic to a point that PHP/Apache thinks it's a failure.  As this is happening on a single user's machine, verify the developer has their local firewall disabled and that they aren't using a proxy server.   Note, the suggestion to enable a proxy to aid debugging could actually be the source of the problem if this developer is the only one using it.

Comment: There is no firewall nor a proxy on the user's computer. We tried turning off Windows native firewall with no luck.